# template function - type checking error - c++

Tags: c++, templates, types

I have this function template

```
template < class TParam >
bool greaterThan (TParam A, TParam B) {
  if (typeid(TParam) == typeid(string)) {   
    return A.compare(B) > 0;   <--------------- Error
  } else {
    return A > B;
  }
}
```

But the compiler won't allow me to use this with an `int`.

I get a compiler error in the place shown above that says

```
Member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union.
```

The if statement does not run if I'm calling the function on an `int`.

I commented it out and checked. I don't know whats wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `TParam` is `int`, with this:

```
A.compare(B)
```

You're trying to call the `compare` method of an `int`. Such a method does not exist. What you need is [template specialisation](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html) so that you can make the template do something special when the type is a certain type:

```
template<class TParam>
bool greaterThan(TParam A, TParam B) {
    return A > B; // this will be called for any type except string because of
                  // our following specialisation
}

// make a specialisation for when the template parameter is string
template<>
bool greaterThan<string>(string A, string B) { 
   return A.compare(B) > 0;
}
```

The syntax is a tiny bit foreign but if you read up on it, template specialisation is a very powerful addition to templates.

Note that `string` does have `operator<` so you don't even need to specialise it if you don't want to, but this is a good opportunity to learn about template specialisation.

Comment: While a specialization is completely valid here, consider that an overload can be provided that accepts the strings by reference while a specialization cannot in this case.  Also, see [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) by Herb Sutter for an interesting comparison of the two approaches.

Comment: Thanks. I tried < operator first, but i think i did something wrong so it wasn't working initially. But It works now. But thanks for info template specialization. I'm sure it'll come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

You know that you are not calling `compare` on an `int`, but the compiler does not: your `if` is evaluated at run-time.

Since `string` is the only special case in your template, try this:

```
template < class TParam >
bool greaterThan (TParam A, TParam B) {
    return A > B;
}
bool greaterThan(const string& a, const string& b) {
    return a.compare(b) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Template code is generated at compile time so the if() statement has not been executed yet.

There are 2 solutions to this

a) provide a specialized version of the template for int's

b) Don't use Compare() - and make it a requirement that struct/classes provide a comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a template function causes the compiler to instantiate the *whole* function and the statement causing the error obviously doesn't work for `int` parameters.  There are a couple of ways to separate the two cases:

First, using a *specialization* of `greaterThan` for strings:

```
template < class TParam >
bool greaterThan (TParam A, TParam B) {
  return A > B;
}

template<>
bool greaterThan< string > (string A, string B) {
  return A.compare(B) > 0;
}
```

Second, using an *overload* of `greaterThan` for strings:

```
template < class TParam >
bool greaterThan (TParam A, TParam B) {
  return A > B;
}

bool greaterThan (string const & A, string const & B) {
  return A.compare(B) > 0;
}
```

In both options, the decision of which function to call is made at compile time as opposed to checking the type at runtime.  Note however that the overload accepts the parameters by *reference* whereas the specialization accepts the parameters by *value* since it must match the signature of the base template function exactly.

Also, with specializations the function chosen by the compiler can sometimes be unexpected.  And since function templates can only be *explicitly* specialized (i.e. not *partially* specialized), overloading offers all of the benefits and none of the drawbacks associated with specializations.

See "[Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)" by Herb Sutter for more information.